# Why can't I use the extern keyword for initializing an extern variable?

Tags: c, language-lawyer, c11

I read in several questions here on stackoverflow and also on other websites, that the `extern` keyword cannot / shall not be used when initializing a global variable.  But I would like to understand, why this is not possible.

Which clauses of the C standard cause, that this is not possible?  I assume it is somewhere hidden in section "6.7 Declarations" or "6.9 External definitions".  I think I fail to find the right paragraph, because I lack knowledge of some constraints from other sections.

What confuses me, is example 1 of section "6.9.2 External object definitions".  Here I find in line 3

```
extern int i3 = 3;  // definition, external linkage
```

which is an initialization of a global variable with the `extern` keyword.  But no word in the example or the associated section indicates, that this would be no "strictly conforming program".

### Code Example:

```
extern int var = 5;

int main(void)
{
        return var;
}
```

When compiling this code with `gcc -Wall -Wextra --pedantic -std=c11 file.c` I get the follwing warning (gcc 8.3.0):

```
file.c:1:12: warning: 'var' initialized and declared 'extern'
 extern int var = 5;
            ^~~
```

Comment: Definite brain/standard teaser. Strange the [C11 Standard - 6.9.2 External object definitions(p4)](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.9.2p4) would use the example `extern int i3 = 3;` where it will invoke a common diagnostic...

Answer (score 7):

The `extern` keyword *can* be used just fine, it's just not very useful.

Your example of

```
extern int var = 5;
```

at global scope is equivalent to

```
int var = 5;  // variable definition
```

Global variables have external linkage by default. Both of those lines define the same variable.

However, if what you're trying to do is to *declare* an external variable (i.e. "this thing exists but is defined elsewhere"), you need to use `extern` without an initializer:

```
extern int var;  // just a declaration; var is defined elsewhere
```

This is analogous to functions, which are defined once:

```
// definition
int foo(void) {
    ...
}
```

And declared wherever they're needed, usually in a header:

```
int foo(void);  // declaration; foo is defined elsewhere
```

Technically you could also use the `extern` keyword with functions:

```
// definition
extern int foo(void) {
    ...
}

extern int foo(void);  // declaration
```

It's just redundant.

The only place where `extern` is not redundant is when declaring (but not defining) global variables, and then you cannot have an initializer (which is part of the definition).

For completeness, you can declare a global variable within a local scope:

```
int main(void) {
    extern int var;
}
```

However, adding an initializer there makes it a hard error:

```
int main(void) {
    extern int var = 42;
}
```

```
try.c:2:16: error: 'var' has both 'extern' and initializer
```

That's because you can only declare (but not define) global variables in a local scope.

In your case, the compiler warns

```
file.c:1:12: warning: 'var' initialized and declared 'extern'
```

because the presence of `extern` usually means the programmer meant to write a variable declaration (why else would you use `extern`?), but the initializer makes it a definition instead.

Comment: One point to use the `extern` keyword is to make the linkage explicit.

Comment: The question is tagged language-lawyer and explicitly asks about clauses of the C standard, but this answer does not cite the standard at all.

Comment: @EricPostpischil True, but the question asks "*Which clauses of the C standard cause, that this is not possible?*". The answer is "none" because it is possible. What am I supposed to cite here?

Comment: @melpomene: The parts that say it is possible.